# TypeError: args.slice(...).join is not a function

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was working on my discord bot and when I tried to run the ban command, this error came. I'm kind of new so can anyone please help me.

**Contacting on discord will help me more:**

my discord: AlanITD#0630

```js
let args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(' ');
let cont = args.shift().toLowerCase();


module.exports.run = async (bot, message) => {
const user = message.mentions.users.first().id // returns the user object if an user mention exists
const banReason = args.slice(1).join(' '); // Reason of the ban (Everything behind the mention)
// Check if an user mention exists in this message
if (!user) {
    try {
// Check if a valid userID has been entered instead of a Discord user mention
           if (!message.guild.members.get(args.slice(0, 1).join(' '))) throw new Error('Couldn\' get a Discord user with this userID!');
// If the client (bot) can get a user with this userID, it overwrites the current user variable to the user object that the client fetched
      user = message.guild.members.get(args.slice(0, 1).join(' '));
     user = user.user;
} catch (error) {
   return message.reply('Couldn\'t get a Discord user with this userID!');
      }
}

if (user === message.author) return message.channel.send('You can\'t ban yourself, stupid '); // Check if the user mention or the entered userID is the message author himsmelf
if (!reason) return message.reply('You forgot to enter a reason for this ban!'); // Check if a reason has been given by the message author
if (!message.guild.member(user).bannable) return message.reply('You can\'t ban this user because you the bot has not sufficient permissions, lmao '); // Check if the user is bannable with the bot's perms

const banConfirmationEmbedModlog = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(`Banned by **${msg.author.username}#${msg.author.discriminator}**`, msg.author.displayAvatarURL)
    .setThumbnail(user.displayAvatarURL)
    .setColor('RED')
    .setTimestamp()
   .setDescription(`**Action**: Ban
**User**: ${user.username}#${user.discriminator} (${user.id})
**Reason**: ${reason}`);
message.channel.send(banConfirmationEmbedModlog)

}

module.exports.config = {
   name: "ban",
   description: "Ban those naughty folks",
   usage: ">ban",
   accessableby: "Moderators and Admins",
   }
```

I would really appreciate all of your support

Comment: May be a types issue. Can you check if `(args || []).slice(1).join(' ')` still triggers the error? Apply the same thing for other `arg.slice` instances as well.

Comment: What's the length of `args`? Does it have more than 1 element? I wonder what happens if you slice starting from an index, that's not in the array.

Comment: it still triggers the error loll @Dan

Comment: @AndriiLukianenko um its a mention argument so it has 1 element i guess?

Comment: Can you check if `message.guild.members.get()` requires the argument to be a function? Since you are passing in a string.